# How to send notification to odoo users when any cron job will fail?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have 100 cron jobs active in my database, If any cron jobs are fail then i want to send notification to users with Error log.

Is there any odoo default configuration available to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already is a solution in the [OCA repositories](https://github.com/OCA/server-tools/tree/db4fdd09a1999781d7e0a40b4cfb9b71cf53159f/scheduler_error_mailer).